# Computed property names. "gulp-angular-filesort : unexpected token ["

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, gulp, ecmascript-6

I need to **asign a JSON property name dynamically**, so I tried with **[computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)**:

```
var dynamicNameProperty = (!irrelevantCondition) ? "name1" : "name2";

var element = {
    "oneStaticNameProp":"Hi!",
    [dynamicProperty] : "Oh oh... This produces an error."
};
```

...but, when I run *`gulp serve`* I get the next error:

```
Error in parsing: "main\templates\dashboard\dashboard.controller.js", Line 160: Unexpected token [
```

[image: error gulp-angular-filesort]

I tried too with **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)**:

```
var dynamicNameProperty["name"] = (!irrelevantCondition) ? "name1" : "name2";

var element = {
    "oneStaticNameProp":"Hi!",
    dynamicNameProperty["name"] : "Oh oh... This produces an error too."
};
```

But I get the same error... So I tried to try luck with **[dot dotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation)**:

```
var myObject = {
    dynamicNameProperty: (!irrelevantCondition) ? "name1" : "name2"
};

var element = {
   "oneStaticNameProp":"Hi!",
   myObject.dynamicNameProperty : "Oh oh... This produces an error too."
};
```

And I get a similar error:

```
Error in parsing: "main\templates\dashboard\dashboard.controller.js", Line 160: Unexpected token .
```

---

Obviously... Something is escaping me. You know any alternative or solution?

---

> **WARNING:** This is only an example of my problem: I can not <strike>and I do not want</strike> just use an if statement for the two states of `dynamicNameProperty`

Comment: I guess my question needs a change of title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the dynamicNameProperty *after* the 'element' object is created:

```
var dynamicNameProperty = (!irrelevantCondition) ? "name1" : "name2";

var element = {
    "oneStaticNameProp":"Hi!"
};

element[dynamicNameProperty] = "Yay....no error here!";
```

Comment: Wow! I knew something escapes me :) That was the only thing I did not try! Thank you.